# Blacklisting roccat module

Tags: modprobe, blacklist

I want the `hid_roccat_ryos` to not load under kernel 3.8.0.

I could blacklist the mouse module `hid_roccat_kovaplus` successfully, but the ryos module, which prevents any external keyboard from working, can't be blacklisted. I wrote into the `blacklist-roccat.conf` the following lines:

```
blacklist hid_roccat_ryos
# blacklist hid_roccat_kovaplus
```

And I cleared the "modprobe dependencies" in the initramfs afterwards

```
sudo update-initramfs -u
```

What else can be done? Maybe a hook or a file loads the module?

Answer (score 0):

As your information is a bit sparse: I guess you have a Roccat device and use the kernel modules and outdated roccat-tools from Arturo Casal's PPA. Please remove the roccat-tools package and compile youself the newest version from source, where this problem is fixed for weeks.

Edit: The problem is that Ubuntu chokes on the file /lib/udev/rules.d/90-roccat-ryos.rules